# Reducing the width of the navbar collapsed menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When the menu collapse when the screen resolution is < 992px , the menu covers the whole width of the screen.

[image: Like so]

But I am trying to reduce the width and set it to 25% like so,

```
.collapse{
    max-width : 25%;
}
```

How can we achieve this?

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awhqobzm/) of the code.

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: I have added a fiddle link please check @Daniel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463368/reduce-width-of-the-collapse-menu

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following css to make the dropdown content to be on center (minimal requirement, so you can make it responsive as you want). And simply shifted `</nav>` tag, before the collapsed items started.

```
  .navbar-collapse
    {
        background-color:#FA0;
        width:200px;
        margin-left:10rem;
    }
```

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: black !important;
}

.nav-link,
.navbar-brand {
  color: white !important;
}

.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 30 30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgb(255,255,255)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}


  .navbar-collapse {
    background-color: #FA0;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 10rem;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light navbar-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-rigth custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon brand-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand ml-auto" href="#">
    <img class="brand-icon" src="resources/img/brandIcon.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
  </a>
  <a class="mr-auto navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
</nav>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse custom-navbar-items" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto navbar-products">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Product One <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Product Two<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Product Three<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Product Four<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-products">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">about us<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you write

```
.navbar.navbar-expand-lg {
     width:25%;
}
```

it will work.